# Advanced Keyboard Settings not persistent across Logins

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, settings, xkb, 23.10

In a fresh Kubuntu 23.04 install, I have set the compose key to be on CapsLock. After every login, I have to open the Keyboard Advanced properties to set it again. Actually the settings display the correct state, but they aren't in effect. What Is needed to make them effective again is to reapply them. Since the "Apply" button is deactivated, one must tick any of the boxes in the advanced section of the keyboard properties so that the Apply button is enabled. Then this setting can be applied. Continuing I then untick that option again and Apply again to return to the state I actually wanted.

This is my kxbrc file for what it's worth:

```
[$Version]
update_info=kxkb.upd:remove-empty-lists,kxkb.upd:add-back-resetoptions,kxkb_variants.upd:split-variants

[Layout]
DisplayNames=,
LayoutList=de,kr
Model=dell
Options=grp:alt_space_toggle,compose:caps,caps:none,eurosign:e,shift:both_capslock
ResetOldOptions=true
Use=true
VariantList=,
```

An update to 23.10 did not solve the issue.

I searched the issue and found [this Manjaro user with a similar or same issue](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/anybody-else-having-keyboard-settings-problems/78175/22), working around it by creating an autorun script which forces the settings.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my Kubuntu 23.04. The setting gets saved in `~/.config/kxkbrc` and for me it survives and is instantly effective after a reboot.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thanks for the report. Could you check with my settings?

Comment: Hmm.. Somehow I screwed it up, because today nothing involving Caps Lock works as expected. Pressing it just opens the same menu as is shown when right clicking with the mouse. I have Kubuntu 23.04 in a VM, which may have something to do with it. I tried that XKB option combo (the options affecting Caps Lock) on Ubuntu 22.04, though, and there it worked fine. Maybe you see some kind of KDE bug and should report it as such.

Comment: Found this related issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues/173

Comment: wHERE CAN i report this bug? what's the right bugtracker for this?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe start here: https://bugs.kde.org/

Comment: Bug filed at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=475783